# How to merge these various statements into more elegant code

Tags: jquery

```
$('.search-input').focus(function () {
    $(this).val('');
});
$('.search-input').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val('enter the place');
    }

});

$('#edit-name').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('.username .error-message').remove();
    } else {
        $('#edit-name').after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message" >enter the name！</span>');
    }
});

$('#edit-name').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('.username .error-message').remove();
        $('#edit-name').after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message" >enter the name！</span>');
    }

});

$('#edit-pass').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('.password .error-message').remove();
    } else {
        $('#edit-pass').after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message"> enter the password！</span>');
    }
});

$('#edit-pass').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('.password .error-message').remove();
        $('#edit-pass').after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message" >enter the password！</span>');
    }

});
```

Is there a way to merge or beauty  the code?thank you.

Comment: First of all, you can chain the event handlers for same selectors.

Comment: This is better suited for codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best functions of jQuery is chaining, in which you can put multiple events with one selector. So you could simply your first two functions like so:

```
$('.search-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()==''){
      $(this).val('enter the place');  
    }
});
```

Another option is to put this all under an event-map, like so:

```
$('.search-input').on({
    focus: function(){
        $(this).val('');
    }, blur: function(){
        if($(this).val()=='') $(this).val('enter the place');  
    }
});
```

If you have the same function but multiple events, you can actually put bind them all at once by using a `.bind` or `.on` (which is much more preferred) and then adding all the events in one. Then, if you would like to select multiple elements, you can also do so by separating them with commas inside the selector. You can reference the relevant element by using `$(this)`.

```
$('#edit-name, #edit-pass').on('keyup blur', function(){
    if($(this).val()!=''){
    $('.username .error-message').remove();
    }else{    
        $(this).after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message" >enter the name！</span>');
    }
});
```

So you see, you only really need two functions without copying the same thing over and over again.

Comment: You can also code `this.value` which is too much better than `$(this).val();`

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple elements in each selector and use `this` to reference the specific one that the event fired for.

Example:

```
$("#foo, #bar").keyup(function() {
  $(this).after('a');
});
```

When you keyup on either `#foo` or `#bar` it will add `a` after that element.

Using this technique, you can combine the two keyup and blur blocks into one each.

Another thing is to chain events:

```
$("#foo, #bar").keyup(function() {
  $(this).after('a');
}).blur(function(){
  $(this).after('b'); 
});
```

This uses the same selector for both keyup and blur events.

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/ulotod/1)

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of chaining with jquery. No need to double select.

For example:

```
$('.search-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
}).blur(function(){
      if( $(this).val()=='' ){
          $(this).val('enter the place');  
    }
});
```

You can do this with the others as well.

Use $(this) when possible:

```
$('#edit-name').blur(function(){
    if( $(this).val()=='' ){
       $('.username .error-message').remove();
  -->>>$(this).after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message" >enter the name！</span>'); 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.search-input').focus(function () {
    $(this).val('');
});
$('.search-input').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val('enter the place');
    }

});
```

You can use placeholder attribute instead of above code.

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="search-input" placeholder="enter the place" />
```

Comment: does `placeholder` in all browsers?